# How to set the axis of symmetry for a line graph and scale the image adaptively around the axis of symmetry in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, linegraph

I have some data about how Apples exchange to Oranges in 5 periods in a market.

```
Period = 1:5;
Apple = [1 2 6 20 3];
Orange = [20 4 15 1 18];
Apple2OrangeExchangeRate = Apple.\Orange
plot(Period,Apple2OrangeExchangeRate,'o-')
```

The variable Apple2OrangeExchangeRate describes in each period how Apples exchange to Oranges. For example, In the first period, 1 Apples exchange to 20 Oranges; and in the forth period, 20 Apples exchange to 1 Orange.
Next, I want to plot the Apple2OrangeExchangeRate in a line graph. In fact, the outcome in the first period and the forth period is symmetrical, because one is 1Apple:20Oranges, and the other is 20Apples:1Orange. If I set Apple2OrangeExchangeRate=1 as the axis of symmetry, they are be of equal status.
[image: It's not symmetric about Apple2OrangeExchangeRate=1]

But in my line graph the first period(rate=20) is too prominent, and the forth period(rate=1/20) is too inconspicuous.
So, for example, how can I make "20:1" and "1:20" look equal in a line graph?

---

```
Period = 1:5;
Apple=[3 0 2 0 1];
Orange = [1 1 0 0 3];
Apple2OrangeExchangeRate=[1/3 0 0 0 3];
plot(Period,Apple2OrangeExchangeRate,'o-')
```

[image]
Maybe I can 'scale' the largest data(In this case is '3') into '2'(but still keep the orginal data in Y axe)? So '0' and '3' are symmetric about '1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A log scale plot will illustrate the "symmetry" of 20:1 vs 1:20:

```
Period = 1:5;
Apple = [1 2 6 20 3];
Orange = [20 4 15 1 18];
Apple2OrangeExchangeRate = Apple.\Orange;
% Plot the log of the exchange rate
ax = axes();
plot(ax, Period,log10(Apple2OrangeExchangeRate),'o-')
% Set the x-axis to go through the origin to emphasize the symmetry
ax.XAxisLocation = 'origin';
ax.YLabel.String = 'log(Apple/Orange)';

% If you want, you can also display the actual exchange rate 
%    values on a second y-axis:
% Get the original y limits
ylimits = ax.YLim;
% Add a second y-axis
yyaxis(ax, 'right');
% Set it to a log scale so it looks nice
ax.YScale = 'log';
% Set the new y-limits to match the old ones on a log scale
ax.YLim = 10.^ylimits;
% Set the 2nd y-axis label
ax.YLabel.String = 'Apple/Orange';
```

Result:

[image: MATLAB figure showing the log plot of Apples/Oranges as described]

Comment: Thanks. But if some data are 0, `log` seems to be helpless. For example, if I I define that when Apples or Oranges is 0, the exchange rate will be 0. `Apple=[20 0 2 0 1], Orange = [1 1 0 0 20], Apple2OrangeExchangeRate=[1/20 0 0 0 20]`

Comment: True, but what do you expect your exchange rate graph to look like when an exchange rate is infinite? How would you represent that on a graph even without the logarithm?

Comment: I have updated the question. In my opinion, exchange rate describes what happen in the market(It's like calculating price of apple in orange). If there is no apple or orange in the market, I can define the price to be 0. Or can I omiss it? So In my second case, the graph should only show the first and the last exchange rate, but still keep five preroid. How to do it?

Comment: I see, I can use `nan` to replace `0`.